# Will async and await help increase the throughput when app makes short multiple db calls?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

The application I am working on uses multiple short duration DB calls to read and update data. The output of one call is being used by the other.

In this scenario whether using await for each DB calls will result in an increase in throughput?

The application and DB are hosted separately.

Proof Of Concept built actually decreased the throughput and I speculate it is because of the overhead of context switching.

Sync version provided roughly 8 req/second, while the async provided only 2.5 req/second.

I have ensured httpTargetRuntime is set to 4.5.2, used aync and await all the way to the asmx service which uses APM style end point as documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#ApmToTap

I am using ADO.NET async versions methods and have set Asynchronous Processing = True in connection string.

1. Should async await be considered good fit for short oltp transactions?
2. How to troubleshoot if the above is because of deadlock. We have done the review of code and did not observe any place where the `.Result` is used from task directly apart from the one mentioned in the link above.

Comment: Even the shortest transaction between client and server will dwarf the cost of a thread context switch, and that's assuming one is even necessary 100% of the time (async operation may or may not require a context switch, depending on how it actually completes). Asking for the Stack Overflow community to share their experience is the epitome of a "too broad" question. Whether "the POC" caused a decrease in throughput would, I suppose, depend on what exactly you mean by "POC". You didn't bother to define that abbreviation.

Comment: Was the app and the db on the same server in the POC?

Comment: @MikaelEliasson have updated question. It uses separate servers.

Comment: @PeterDuniho have updated the poc details

Comment: Yeah, but you still didn't bother to define "POC". Do you mean "proof-of-concept"? Why are you making people _guess_ at what you mean?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes it is proof-of-concept. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you are not accessing them in parallel. Async and Await just return the context to the caller, thus making the main thread not have to wait. But the same amount of work needs to be done, with or without Async Await, and it's done waiting every call to pass the result to the next (plus the context switching).

I would recommend rewriting your logic to be able to call only one request to the database, creating a stored procedure if necessary, for example.

Comment: Thanks. We are looking at SP option as next step. I understand the response time will not decrease because of async and await, but as the idle threads are available to process other requests shouldn't the throughput increase?

Comment: Yes, but only for the other requests that runs in the thread that called the async method (ie. user interface), not the awaited ones (ie. db connection).

Comment: For example, your UI contains two buttons (A and B) that make independent requests to the DB, and those requests have a duration of about 3 seconds. The user clicks in button A, and after one second, clicks button B. Without Async/Await, the user would need to wait 6 seconds to both operations complete. With async/await on both calls, just 4 seconds, because now they are executed in parallel (and without freezing the UI).

Comment: Thanks for the example. In my case this is a ASMX webservice exposed and when performing the load testing the throughput achieved is less compared to sync version

Comment: Yes, probably due to the context switching. Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: No Plain ADO.NET